# getting base url of registered jquery.ui in yii

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

This the code in my `/config/main.php`

```
'packages'=>array(
                'jquery'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
                ),
                'jquery.ui'=>array(
                    'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/',
                    'js'=>array('jquery-ui.min.js'),
                )
            ),
```

and in my layout i have loaded jquery, jquery.ui using

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');?>
    <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');?>
```

I want to get the base url of jquer.ui (i.e`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/`) is there any method that will return me the baseUrl of jquery.ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [getPackageBaseUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#getPackageBaseUrl-detail)

Also if you need to see the source then [get it here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/CClientScript.php#L532)

For egs you can get uri like,

```
<?php
    echo Yii::app()->clientScript->getPackageBaseUrl('jquery.ui');
?>
```

See [this](http://danaluther.blogspot.in/2012/03/using-packages-with-clientscript.html) which will clear you more about `package`.